# Detect if a boolean changes Angular 8

Tags: html, angular, typescript, observable

I have this ngbCollapse in my html:

```
<div style="margin: 1.5em 1.5em;" [ngbCollapse]="isCollapsed">
//things
</div>
```

In my component, I would call a method everytime isCollapsed changes:

```
export class Component implements OnInit {

public isCollapsed = true;

constructor(private Serv: _service) {}

  ngOnInit() {}

//Everytime isCollapsed changes I would call this method
isCollapsedInService () {
 this._service.set(isCollapsed);
}
```

Comment: Thats what observables / subjects are made for: https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/observable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you use Event Binding in Angular

In Angular 8, event binding is used to handle the events raised from the DOM like button click, mouse movement etc. When the DOM event happens (eg. click, change), it calls the specified method in the component.

[https://www.javatpoint.com/event-binding-in-angular-8#:~:text=In%20Angular%208%2C%20event%20binding,specified%20method%20in%20the%20component](https://www.javatpoint.com/event-binding-in-angular-8#:%7E:text=In%20Angular%208%2C%20event%20binding,specified%20method%20in%20the%20component).

Comment: I would like to bind on click, but i tried <div style="margin: 1.5em 1.5em;" [ngbCollapse]="isCollapsed" (click)="isCollapsedInService()"> and the method does not be called.

Answer (score 1):

In html file

`<button (click)="isCollapsedInService($event)">Btn</button> <!--Event Binding-->`

In .ts file

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';    
@Component({    
  selector: 'app-root',    
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',    
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']    
})    
export class AppComponent {      
 isCollapsedInService($event){    
    console.log("Button is clicked!", $event);    
  }    
}
```